# Call method without a triggering condition

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a program which will randomly and continuously display circles all over the screen that will change sizes. I've created a method that will draw circles but I'm not sure how to call it. In the past I've only done buttons which will call a method when clicked, but I don't know how to just call a method out of the blue. Is there a 'main method equivalent' in android which is automatically run?

Answer (score 1):

The `onCreate` method of the activity showing the circles will be automatically run. From here you can start a background timer thread to randomly call the method creating the circles.

Comment: Just curious, is that the only way or are there more options?

Comment: @Sygnerical - I'm sure there are other ways. This is just a simple one.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `main method`, but you can not touch it simply. In Android , the UI thread would be the `main method` you want though they are not the same thing.

You can run action in UI thread like this:

```
public static void runInUiThread(Runnable action) {
    if (Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper()) {
        action.run();
    } else {
        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(action);
    }
}
```

But according to your question ,you want to display something. It is not a google idea that draw it directly on `Activity`, you can create a class and `extends View`. The `Override` the `onDraw` method , you can put your drawing code into `onDraw`. This function will be called automatically when it need to be display.

Now you can put your custom view into layout and if the custom view need to be display in screen , it would.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own class enxtends `View`, and put the code that controlls the appearance of the circle in the mothod `onDraw()` which you should override.When you want to get the size of your circle changed, call `invalidate()`.As a result, the method `onDraw()` is called and the appearance just changes.